# Delete a node in firebase if the Object is incomplete

Tags: java, android, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database

I have nodes in firebase like this, this is the correct node
[image]

But when I upload a result, it is supposed to delete the node.....Delete all correct, but after a few minutes this appears in the database (I know my problem is in the java, but I need a faster temporary solution
[image]

My question is, how can I detect and delete a node if the node contain less attributes than the correct node (20+), or in java how to detect if an object is smaller than is supposed to be.

```
mMatchesPlayDatabaseReference.child(matchId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                Match match = dataSnapshot.getValue(Match.class);

                adapter.setFriendsList(stringArrayList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: get the results and check for the `length` property

Comment: but how i can check the length of an object?? When i receive the second object with 3 elements it crash, because it supposed to receive an object with 10 elements. how check the lenght of the data i receive before assign the data to the object, to avoid it crash. Thanks

Comment: please put some code.

Comment: i edit the question

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to use `getChildrenCount()` method on the dataSnapshot object. In this way you can check if the number of childrens is less than the number of properties that exists in your POJO class.

I also recomand you to use [addOnCompleteListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.firebase.tasks.OnCompleteListener<T>)) method when writing data to the database. Is adds a listener that is called when the Task completes.